# How to edit a Build Job in Jenkins Freestyle Project v2.289

Tags: jenkins

I am working on the jenkins v2.289 and i want to edit the bash script that i have already test. But on the interface i can't found my old script to edit it.

I work on CentOs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SPWR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide more information, is that a previous pipeline that you have created and after some run you want to edit the pipeline? or is this a new pipeline?
On an existing pipeline in your screenshot you should be seeing your shell like this:
[image]

if it's a new one you should select from the drop-down menu in "add build step" "execute shell".

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Yes, i found it now.